# PNG -- extract transparency mask, color, then reapply

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, transparency, photoshop-cs6

I have a PNG which is basically some icons colored in certain ways, with a transparency mask around the edges of them.

I want to recolor these icons in certain ways.

The way I want to approach it is to extract the transparency mask, lazily color the icons allowing overflow into surrounding areas, then apply the mask over the top of it to cut the icons back to their exact shape, with the new colors applied.

I have Photoshop CS8.

I have found a way to right click on the layer and "Select layer transparency", but after that I am not sure. There are options to add/subtract/intersect the transparency mask, but it is not clear how to simply extract it and have it as a separate layer I can toggle on and off.

Thanks

Comment: I never knew there is a Photoshop Creative Suite 8, I though the last version of PS CS is CS6, then it directly goes into Creative Cloud (CC)...

Comment: Sorry it might be just CS1 (version 8)

Comment: I think you should update your software, please consider to use at least Photoshop CS6...

Comment: Have you tried locking the layer's transparency (in the layers window)

Comment: I saw that lock option, but I am not fully sure how it helps solve this problem.

Comment: Oh Wow, that works!